# inline-block does not work css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display the following two sections in line and vertical-align: top but any of the two works.

```
<section id="info">

        <div class="client-label">N° Portefeuille: </div>

        <div class="client-edit">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.portfolio) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.portfolio)
         </div>
</section>
<section id="record">
 <i>Voici la dernière restriction que vous avez ajouté: </i> 
          <h3> Portfolio </h3>

          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.portfolio) 
</section>
```

CSS code:

```
#info, #record {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
#record {
border: 1px solid midnightblue;
padding: 5px;
float: right;
display:inline;
}
#info{
display: inline
}
```

For sure there is something wrong but I can't see where is the problem.
So could someone make some light on this issue.

Thank you !

Comment: A jsFiddle which reproduces the issue would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this:

## info{

display: inline;
        float:left;
}

or try this: [inline described here](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)

Comment: I have already try this but everything goes bad when I do this the div that are after are displayed behind the two sections that I talk about !

Comment: i am not sure if I get your question. But see this : http://jsfiddle.net/ztr78rg2/1/ this might help.

Comment: thank you but it is exactly the same I do it in visual studio because I develop an asp.net mvc app. Maybe it is because of the <fieldset> everything that I mention is include in it. Is this might cause problem ?

Comment: well, if you have fieldset and other stuff, you should edit your question and add those. Otherwise it is not possible to re-produce that.

Comment: It is ok now thank you for your help , I don't see that I close the first section after the second one because I have included the second one !